# cuda integer of 16 bits

Tags: cuda, uint

is there any 16 bits long variable in CUDA? I need an unsigned integer of 16 bits. I've tried:

```
uint16
uint16_t
```

But no one is recognized by nvcc.

Comment: uint16_t is a typedef in stdint.h. Add #include <stdint.h> to your file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be you should try ordinary c `unsigned short`?

Answer (score 5):

CUDA 8 (compute capability 6.x) comes with [half-precision intrinsics](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/mixed-precision-programming-cuda-8/). You can use the 16-bit floating point data type `half` or the integral types `short2` / `char4`. These mixed precision types are packed into 32-bit device registers, which can double your performance over [just using](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12733856/5495432) `unsigned short`.

Comment: some SO answers suggest that using composite types also speeds up code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676806/efficiency-of-cuda-vector-types-float2-float3-float4